# Real-time UDP multiplayer games: ping measurement?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, udp, latency

In real-time multiplayer games that use UDP for the actual game (CS:S, UT, etc.), how is network latency (ping) measured? More specifically, how do you find out how long ago a UDP packet was sent?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm very new to network programming.

Comment: Update: on the Quake 3 Networking Model page (http://web.archive.org/web/20110718080312/http://trac.bookofhook.com/bookofhook/trac.cgi/wiki/Quake3Networking), there's a mention of unreliable acks. Would this be a good approach — send out a bunch of unreliable UDP packets, noting their sequence number, and then record (halve?) the round-trip time when an ack for a packet returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just send some 'ping', write timestamp of that packet/session, wait for 'pong' response and get timestamp 'now' and divide the difference by two.

Comment: Thank you! In retrospect, this seems really obvious, but I'm really new to all this. :)